# Hiding a dynamically created table row on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide, rows

I'm currently trying to hide a dynamically created table row after a button has been pressed. So far I have managed to handle part of the dynamic functions.

Each dynamic row has a "Cancel" and "Save" button, I have managed to respond to these with ease. My problem is actually working with the row itself.

```
$(function() {
    $(".add").click(function(){
        // Just append to the table
        $("table#bookmarks tr:first").after("<tr class='new' id='<?php echo rand(1, 9999); ?>'><td></td><td><b>URL:</b> <input type='text' id='newURL' /><br /><b>Title:</b> <input type='text' id='newTitle' /><br /><b>Description:</b><br /><textarea id='newDesc'></textarea></td><td><b>Tags:</b> <input type='text' id='newTags' /></td><td><a href='#' class='save'>Save</a><br /><a href='#' class='cancel'>Cancel</a></td></tr>");
        $('span#links').html('<i style="color: #FF0000">You must reload to recount links!</i>');
        // Actually, the user doesn't want to add another link
        $('.cancel').click(function() {
            $(this).parents(".new").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        });
        // Seems the user wants to add a link!
        $('.save').click(function() {
            $("table#bookmarks tr.new #id").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        });
    });

});
```

I need to now hide the row, I have tried all sorts of various methods, .parent, .attr to name a few.

Comment: What do you mean by "My problem is actually working with the row itself"?

Also, you're using the selector $("table#bookmarks tr.new #id") but you don't have any element with id="id".

Comment: I know this is old, but for others who may not understand. You hit it on the nose when you said the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaining your jQuery functions like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        $("<tr class='new'><td></td><td><b>URL:</b> <input type='text' id='newURL' /><br /><b>Title:</b> <input type='text' id='newTitle' /><br /><b>Description:</b><br /><textarea id='newDesc'></textarea></td><td><b>Tags:</b> <input type='text' id='newTags' /></td></tr>")
            .append($("<td></td>")
                .append($("<a href='#'>Save</a><br/>")
                    .click(function() { $(this).parents(".new").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow"); }))
                .append($("<a href='#'>Cancel</a>")
                    .click(function() { $(this).parents(".new").animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF0000" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow"); })))
            .insertAfter($("table#bookmarks tr:first"));
            $('span#links').html('<i style="color: #FF0000">You must reload to recount links!</i>');
    });
});
```

(This is a modified version of your original code so it's still a bit messy.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery live, new since jQuery 1.3.2, to preserve the click function on a dynamically created item.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: Thank you for your response, I shall try adding this now.

Comment: jQuery live is a beautiful thing but it doesn't support ALL events - in your case it should be fine as click is supported but for custom events http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery provides the same functionality.

Comment: Ravi, can you suggest where to position the code and how it should be called? I am pretty sure I have the elements being called correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I tossed together a quick example but I'll admit I'm a tad rusty on jQuery.  This code however does work, at least for me.

```
$(function() {
$(".add").click(function(){
    var save = $("<a href='#' class='save'>Save</a>").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
    })

    var cancel = $("<a href='#' class='cancel'>Cancel</a>").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, "fast").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
    })

    var buttonTD = $("<td></td>");
    buttonTD.append(save);
    buttonTD.append(cancel);

    var row = $("<tr class='new' id='<?php echo rand(1, 9999); ?>'><td></td><td><b>URL:</b> <input type='text' id='newURL' /><br /><b>Title:</b> <input type='text' id='newTitle' /><br /><b>Description:</b><br /><textarea id='newDesc'></textarea></td><td><b>Tags:</b> <input type='text' id='newTags' /></td></tr>")
    .append(buttonTD);
});
```

});

Comment: You dug this post up how many months after it was posted?  How many appends?  I think you might be a little rusty on your knowledge.

Comment: buttonTD.append(save);buttonTD.append(cancel); Should be done in one go. Appends cause a redraw which hurts performance.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery live function:

```
$("#sendmail").live("click", function(){

    // your code goes here  


});
```

here is an example of how I used it.

```
$("#sendmail").live("click", function(){

    $("#emailres").html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif">');
    var youremail = $("#youremail").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'email.php',
    data: 'youremail=' + youremail + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message,

    success: function(results) {
        $('#emailres').html(results);
        }
    }); // end ajax 

});
```

To hide the selected row, do something like this:

first give your table an id (something like #mytable)

```
$("#cancel_row").live("click", function(){

    $(this).$("#mytable tr").hide();

});
```

hope that helps you.

Comment: Brilliant, that shows me a good example for using jQuery live. Thanks A Hassan!